# What makes long integer numerical values (16+ chars) to mutate in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, integer, long-integer

Is there anybody could **explain the reason** why the following is happening in JavaScript?

```
let x212 = 154688977320418212;
// returns 154688977320418200

let x230 = 154688977320418230;
// returns 154688977320418240

let x256 = 154688977320418256;
// returns 154688977320418240

let x257 = 154688977320418257;
// returns 154688977320418270
```

Does it mean that there is no way to store long integer value, without converting it to string?

Comment: Those numbers are higher than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (`9007199254740991`) so, they are (as you can guess), not safe to use. You need a big number library and/or represent them as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, all numbers are 64 bits **floating point numbers**.

The size of the mantissa is about 53 bits, which means that your number, `154688977320418257`, can't be **exactly** represented as a JavaScript number. What you see is an approximation, because it's a number higher than `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (i.e 9007199254740991).

If you really need big numbers, you could use a lib such as https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js.